# Convert complex (multiple child) XML element to comment while maintaining formatting

Tags: xml, powershell, comments

Given XML of

```
<Root>
    <Element>
        <Child1 />
        <Child2 />
        <Child3 />
    </Element>
</Root>
```

I am looking to wrap the entire `<element>` in a single comment, maintaining formatting. So either

```
<!--<Element>
    <Child1 />
    <Child2 />
    <Child3 />
</Element>-->
```

or

```
<!--
<Element>
    <Child1 />
    <Child2 />
    <Child3 />
</Element>
-->
```

But so far, the only thing I have been able to do is use `.InnerXml` to reduce the entire element to a single line comment

```
<!--<Element><Child1 /><Child2 /><Child3 /></Element>-->
```

Which in this example isn't a problem, but in my real world XML with a lot more elements plus the contents of them, becomes basically unusable for my use case.

Is there a simple solution I am missing? Or would I need to process the entire element into text lines and deal with indenting and line ends myself?

Comment: You can use SelectNodes to grab the `Element` then use `XmlWriter` to create the new string

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
using assembly System 
using assembly System.Xml.Linq 

$Filename = "c:\temp\test.xml"
$xDoc = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Load($Filename)

$element =  $xDoc.Descendants("Element").Foreach([System.Xml.Linq.XElement])
$comment = New-Object -TypeName System.Xml.Linq.XComment([string]$element)

$element.ReplaceWith($comment)
Write-Host $xDoc
```